# calling multiple functions on same line not working in Scala shell

Tags: scala

I am trying to define the following function in Scala shell which accepts 3 separate functions as arguments and then calls these functions:-

```
 def myfun(f1:(Int)=>Unit,f2:(Int,Int)=>Unit,f3:(Int,Int,Int)=>Unit) = f1(1); f2(1,2); f3(1,2,3)
```

The Scala shell throws an errors saying:-

```
<console>:22: error: not found: value f3
        f3(1,2,3)
        ^ <console>:20: error: not found: value f2
              def myfun(f1:(Int)=>Unit,f2:(Int,Int)=>Unit,f3:(Int,Int,Int)=>Unit) = f1(1); f2(1,2);;
```

But if I call these functions on separate lines in the body of the function, it works perfectly:-

```
scala> def myfun(f1:(Int)=>Unit,f2:(Int,Int)=>Unit,f3:(Int,Int,Int)=>Unit) = {
     | f1(1)
     | f2(1,2)
     | f3(1,2,3)
     | }
myfun: (f1: Int => Unit, f2: (Int, Int) => Unit, f3: (Int, Int, Int) => Unit)Unit
```

What I read is that scala supports calling several functions on the same line as long as they are separated by semicolon. Then why is this behaving differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap them into a block:

```
... = { f1(1); f2(1,2); f3(1,2,3) }
```

The code you have is equivalent to:

```
def myfun(f1: (Int) => Unit, f2: (Int, Int) => Unit, f3: (Int, Int, Int) => Unit) = f1(1)
f2(1, 2)
f3(1, 2, 3)
```